# 2 WebView controls and Scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp

I need to use 2 webviews control horizontally to show 2 html page contenst at the same time and i use the below xaml

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <WebView  Name="myView"  Grid.Row="1" NavigationCompleted="myView_NavigationCompleted" ></WebView>
    <WebView Name="myViewRight"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" NavigationCompleted="myViewRight_NavigationCompleted"></WebView>
</Grid>
```

This layout keeps 2 webviews next to next and html contents are showing . But when it comes to scrolling it is not good that 2 uses seperate scrollbars [ in built scroll of browser]
So i decided to disable the built in scrollbar using the code

```
var script = "document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';document.body.style.background = 'red';";

await myView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { script });
await myViewRight.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { script });
```

Now i want a common ScrollViewer for both web views
Is it possbile to create such a scrollbar ? Like when we scroll it should scroll contents for both web views ?
I tried to keep a ScrollViewer on top of Grid with 2 webviews but cant get the expected effect
Is any alternate approach to implement the simmilar UI? or how can i make a single ScrollViewer for both webviews